# How to click the buttons A to Z using Selenium and Python within the webpage http://architects-register.org.uk/list/regions

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

http://architects-register.org.uk/list/regions

So i have this website which i want to be able to have the code click the button A, then B and C and so on. How should i do that. I tried this code which tries to get the value of the child of the element then click the buttons accordingly but it does not work. I suspect there's some other issues aside the error below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'http://architects-register.org.uk/'
driver.get(url)

find_uk = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_hlCountiesT').click()

elements = alphabets[0].find_element_by_tag_name('li')

def getChild(el):
   return el.children[0].children[0]

for element in elements:
    element = element[elements]
    (getChild(element)).click()
```

`NameError: name 'alphabets' is not defined`

Comment: maybe the problem is that variable 'alphabets' is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alphabets` isn't being imported or defined anywhere in the given code block, so trying to access an index on it will fail in the way shown. It looks like `alphabets` should probably be the result of calling `find_elements_by_tag_name` or `find_elements_by_class_name` which would return a list of your buttons which you could then iterate over and click on.

Answer (score 1):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and then click on each link.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://architects-register.org.uk/'
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ctl00_hlCountiesT"))).click()
elements =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='alphabet_list_content']//li//input")))
for ele in range(len(elements)):
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='alphabet_list_content']//li//input")))
    elements[ele].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the button **A**, then **B** and **C** and so on you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("http://architects-register.org.uk/list/regions")
  for i in range(1, len(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.alphabet_list_content>ul li"))))):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.alphabet_list_content>ul li:nth-of-type({})>a>input".format(i)))).click()
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("http://architects-register.org.uk/list/regions")
  for i in range(1, len(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='alphabet_list_content']/ul//li"))))):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='alphabet_list_content']/ul//following-sibling::li[{}]/a/input".format(i)))).click()
  driver.quit()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```